# What is the javascript equivalent of Jquery's .load() shorthand method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is for the non-depreciated new jquery .load() ajax shorthand method.

For example, what is the equivalent javascript of the following jquery ajax shorthand method?

```
$("#targetdiv").load("page.html");
```

Comment: When in doubt, there's always the jQuery source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js  This function makes an AJAX request and sets the response as the HTML content of the target element.

Comment: please do accept/upvote if you get info you want

Comment: Oliver, that's for the depreciated .load()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` object is javascript object allows ajax request , below is example of same (under the hood library like jquery use this object only to for ajax request)

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working.

Comment: xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "page.html", true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
  document.getElementById("targetdiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
 }
}

Comment: That above seems to work for some reason. I have to put the .open and .send at the top or it doesn't work.  This looks so different than the jquery library load.js , sorry for the weird format.

Comment: @MorganMarshall - i think open than send is sequence but onreadystatechange is event you can write before it ....Please do accept/upvote if answer worked for you ....

Comment: This does work great, thanks Pranay Rana. Is this the modern way to do this and does anyone have  links to some official docs?

Comment: @MorganMarshall - you can google thre are lot of information available on this ...by the way this is pure javascript ...i suggest go for jquery but understanding basic alway help